# How do I remove unrecognized characters which come back from a web service?

Tags: java, xml, android, parsing, encoding

I am working on an app which calls a rest web service.  Sometimes the xml responses contain characters which the phone can not display.  When displaying these characters, an empty box is displayed instead.  I would like to filter out these characters.  How can I detect if a character will be able to be displayed on the screen?

Some specific characters include:

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0094/index.htm 
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0080/index.htm 
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0092/index.htm

Comment: Are you sure it is a problem of "understanding" (unrecognized XML entities) and not just "display" (application font missing certain Unicode code-points)? If it is the former, the answer is to clean the XML before reading it in; if it is the latter, your problem can be solved by choosing (or bundling) another font with more code-points.

Comment: can you explain what kind of characters are not being displayed correctly. Also, what fonts are you using.

Comment: If you could post more informations like the charackters that are not shown correctly we could give you a not that general answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Android support the following [encodings](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Xml.Encoding.html)

- Xml.Encoding  ISO_8859_1
- Xml.Encoding  US_ASCII
- Xml.Encoding  UTF_16
- Xml.Encoding  UTF_8

US_ASCII shouldn't make any problems.

For ISO_8859_1 you should check [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)
for control chars 0x00-0x1f and 0x7f-0x9f and filter them.
And of course use a matching font.

Using UTF_8 or 16 is more complex, read Joels [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

You might find this mailing [list](http://osdir.com/ml/Android-Developers/2010-04/msg01108.html) useful.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, try to get the default charset of your device with:

```
Charset.defaultCharset();
```

Then try to get the charset of your XML looking in pseudo-attribute of the XML declaration or in Content-Type header of the HTTP call.
For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

or

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

If the default charset of your device is different from the charset of XML, you have to pay attention when you handle new strings with:

```
new String( bytes);
```

because if you forget to specify the correct encoding, Dalvik will use the default encoding of the device with plausible display errors.
Remember to use:

```
new String( bytes, encoding);
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears I can call `Character.isIdentifierIgnorable()` on each character and not include it if it is ignorable.  `Character.isISOControl()` will probably also work.