# Android unrecognized characters are displayed as "?"

Tags: android, parsing

I have an app than parses a csv and diplays its content. My problem is it displays '-' as '?' inside a diamond. What can I do so that it wouldn't display as such?

EDIT: here's my code for opening the file

```
InputStream input = openFileInput("pms.csv");
SchedController.reader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(input, "US-ASCII"));
SchedController.sched = SchedController.reader.readAll();
input.close();
```

I have tried `US-ASCII`, `UTF-8`...

Comment: check your character encoding...

Comment: there must be encoding of special characters issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The suggested encodings on the previous answers did not solve my case. I tried the encoding "windows-1252" which I found out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6192910/converting-a-txt-file-from-ansi-to-utf-8-programaticaly) and it worked:

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(input, "windows-1252"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set Encoding type by:

```
StandardFonts.WIN_ANSI_ENCODING
```

or can make changes in the string as:

```
       newString = oldString.replace(")", "\\)");
       newString = oldString.replace("(", "\\(");
```

Comment: hi, where exactly in the activity can I put `StandardFonts.WIN_ANSI_ENCODING`?

Comment: where u r trying to set font or text u may apply there as setFont(StandardFonts.SUBTYPE, StandardFonts.TIMES_ROMAN, StandardFonts.WIN_ANSI_ENCODING);

Comment: ah.. like if I have a `TextView` `name.setFont(StandardFonts.SUBTYPE, StandardFonts.TIMES_ROMAN, StandardFonts.WIN_ANSI_ENCODING);` ? Like that?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing character encoding to **UTF-8**

```
SchedController.reader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(input, "UTF-8"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also refer to below post

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2680834/1441666

Android support the following encodings

- Xml.Encoding ISO_8859_1
- Xml.Encoding US_ASCII
- Xml.Encoding UTF_16
- Xml.Encoding UTF_8